# Using column names with signs of a data frame in a qplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have a dataset and unfortunately some of the column labels in my `dataframe` contain signs (- or +). This doesn't seem to bother the `dataframe`, but when I try to plot this with `qplot` it throws me an error:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- x
names <- c("1+", "2-")

mydf <- data.frame(x, y)
colnames(mydf) <- names
mydf
qplot(1+, 2-, data = mydf)
```

and if I enclose the column names in quotes it will just give me a category (or something to that effect, it'll give me a plot of "1+" vs. "2-" with one point in the middle).

Is it possible to do this easily? I looked at aes_string but didn't quite understand it (at least not enough to get it to work).

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have searched for a solution online but can't quite find anything that helps me with this (it could be due to some aspect I don't understand), so I reason it might be because this is a completely retarded naming scheme I have :p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the other answer you have a problem because you you don't have standard names.  When solution is to avoid `backticks` notation is to convert colnames to a standard form. Another motivation to  convert names to regular ones is , you can't use `backticks` in a `lattice` plot for example. Using `gsub` you can do this:

```
 gsub('(^[0-9]+)[+|-]+|[+|-]+','a\\1',c("1+", "2-","a--"))
[1] "a1" "a2" "aa"
```

Hence, applying this to your example :

```
 colnames(mydf) <- gsub('(^[0-9]+)[+|-]+|[+|-]+','a\\1',colnames(mydf))
 qplot(a1,a2,data = mydf)
```

**EIDT**

you can use `make.names` with option unique =T

```
 make.names(c("10+", "20-",  "10-", "a30++"),unique=T)
[1] "X10."  "X20."  "X10..1" "a30.."
```

If you don't like R naming rules, here a custom version with using `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("[+|-]|^[0-9]+", 
function(x) switch(x,'+'= 'a','-' ='b',paste('x',x,sep='')),
c("10+", "20-",  "10-", "a30++"))
"x10a"  "x20b"  "x10b" "a30aa"    ## note x10b looks better than X10..1
```

Comment: or use `names(mydf) <- make.names(names(mydf))`, if you don't mind using R's default rules for such sanitizing.

Comment: @BenBolker excellent !! maybe this will not work if he has something like `make.names(c('a+','a-'))`.

Comment: yes, although that fails (= leads to identical column names) with your solution as well ...

Comment: This is wonderful, I was afraid this would be a major problem (I actually tried this with forward ticks before with no success.. didn't realize they had to be back ticks). And there's a lot of options on how to deal with this..

Answer (score 3):

Since you have non-standard column names, you need to to use backticks (`)in your column references.

For example:

```
mydf$`1+`
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

So, your `qplot()` call should look like this:

```
qplot(`1+`, `2-`, data = mydf)
```

[image]

---

You can find more information in `?Quotes` and `?names`